# How to store data in ImageView in android dynamically?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Subject of interest : Android

After hours of searching I couldn't find or understand how to create ImageView dynamically to store associative data and perform an action depending on the image view clicked.

Let me elaborate ,
I am creating a grid of ImageViews using GridLayout (as gridview examples are too complex for me). I am able to create the grid but still struggling with alignment issues.
So now I have this Grid of ImageViews, but from what I learned, the Id's of these ImageViews are converted to integers at run time. But I need these IDs as I use them to fetch data from server depending on their uniqueness. Is there a way to store other data than the Ids in ImageView Tags?. I come from a web development background where I could use JavaScript easily to create elements with dynamic Ids to refer later and use in queries. So please guide me.

**UPDATE:**
I tried using the SetId method, and that is when I got this doubt. Because SetId only lets me set IntegerIDs. What if I needed alphanumeric ID to be used later for querying purposes?.

**Exam_Screen.Java**

```
public class Exam_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {

GridLayout gridLayout;
public int[] QArray;

private int[] GetQuestionsFromServer() {
    return new int[50];
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam__screen);
    QArray = GetQuestionsFromServer();
    AddQuestionsToScrollArea(QArray);
}
public void AddQuestionsToScrollArea(int[] QArray)
{
    gridLayout = findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
    gridLayout.removeAllViews();

    int total = QArray.length;
    int column = 4 ;
    int row = total / column;
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(column);
    gridLayout.setRowCount(row + 1);
    //gridLayout
    for (int i = 0, c = 0, r = 0; i < total; i++, c++) {
        if (c == column) {
            c = 0;
            r++;
        }
        ImageView oImageView = new ImageView(this);
        oImageView.setScaleX(0.3f);
        oImageView.setScaleY(0.3f);
        oImageView.setId(i); // I want to set the Ids I get from Server, and use them later
        oImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        oImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        oImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_candidate_image);

        GridLayout.LayoutParams lp = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        lp.width = 30;
        lp.height = 30;
        lp.topMargin = 5;
        lp.bottomMargin = 5;
        lp.leftMargin = 5;
        lp.rightMargin = 5;

        oImageView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        GridLayout.Spec rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1);
        GridLayout.Spec colspan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1);
        if (r == 0 && c == 0) {
            Log.e("", "spec");
            Log.d("Column", "value: " + column);
            Log.d("rows", "value: " + row);
            colspan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1);
            rowSpan = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, 1);
        }

        GridLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(
                rowSpan, colspan);
        gridLayout.addView(oImageView, gridParam);
    }
}
}
```

**Relevant Exam Screen Activity XML**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border">
    <GridLayout
         android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager to make grid dynamically and set the URL of images in the  imageView using the library such as Picasso or Glide

Comment: You should paste your code so we have a better idea of what you are looking at :)

Comment: @KartikAgarwal I don't need dynamic images from somewhere, I just need same image repeated. I need unique Ids or some way to set the unique data to each ImageView and then on click of each ImageView I need to show data by fetching from server using that unique Id or attribute.